# WPF Object Reference not set to Instance of Object

Tags: wpf, nullreferenceexception

In Windows Presentation Foundation I am getting errors in the designer on this line:

```
<WindowsPresentation:GMapControl x:Name="MainMap" Zoom="13" MaxZoom="24" MinZoom="1" Margin="0,145,0,0" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" />
```

However, the program runs just fine. I'm totally stumped. The designer also renders perfectly. It's just an error in the errors list.

Comment: The F in WPF is Foundation not Forms ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, already found the solution.

It turns out that the amazing [GMaps Control](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/) has a bug in which declaring Zoom in the WPF XAML syntax will raise a NullReferenceException. Removing this tag has fixed the issue:

```
<WindowsPresentation:GMapControl x:Name="MainMap" CanDragMap="True"  MaxZoom="24" MinZoom="1"  Margin="0,145,0,0" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" />
```

I hope this helps someone with the same problem.